# C: buffer overflow, changing passed variables

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow, strcat

I'm doing some exercises regarding buffer overflows and I am currently stumped as how to proceed further with one of them. This is the program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>


void reverb(char *msg, unsigned int len) {

  unsigned char length = (unsigned char) len;
  char buffer[250] = "Printed: ";

  strcat(buffer + 9, msg);

  if ((length > 75) || (length < 15)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid string length");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buffer);
  }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  //argument check
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid arguments!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  reverb(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));

  return 0;
}
```

So basically as obvious as it is, this program should just re-print the argument you gave to it. I obviously have to exploit one of the functions used, and I suspect the main culprit here is strcat. However, I'm faced with the issue of the `length` variable when I want to get my stack smashing done.

To be able to cause a segfault and successfully find a point for the overflow to happen, I need to pass an argument with a length of around 255+ (not sure on the current number right now but it's somewhere around that), which is not doable with my 75 char limit. Using gdb and setting a break point right after `strcat`, I am able to find the `buffer`'s location in the memory (kinda easy, just the area filled with 0x41 since I spammed it with A's). `length`'s location was kinda trickier, but here's the issue - it's located BEFORE the buffer, meaning I couldn't even overwrite it if I wanted. But, I somehow still need to overwrite it to get into the else branch, I think. And I've been stuck at that point, not seeing a way to proceed properly.

Comment: Hint: What happens if `len` exceeds the size of a `char`? ;)

Comment: You want `len % 255` between 15 and 75. So add any multiple of 255 to any number between 15 and 75.

Comment: "this program should just re-print the argument you gave to it." --> not if the length of the argument is 256.  @MadPhysicist Off-by-one: it is "`len % 256` between 15 and 75"

Comment: @chux. You are absolutely right. Replace 255 by 256 throughout my previous comment.

Comment: @Siguza Does `void reverb(char *msg, unsigned int len) ... reverb(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));` give a compiler warning?  Are all warnings enabled?
`

Comment: Just a note:  If you change strcat(buffer + 9, msg); to strcat(buffer, msg);, it will still work if the length of the string in buffer changes, while with the +9 it won't.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is long - say 256 chars, the Length variable will be wrong.  Use the suggestions in the comments to catch it.

The crash: the string copy will then copy all 256 chars onto the end of the string in buffer, which only can hold 250 bytes.

Move the strcpy() into the else.

**Additional notes:**

I ran this in my debugger (VS2015)

When passing in the 256 byte string and overrunning “buffer”, the variable “length” got clobbered, and its value changes from 0 to 69 (some character in my string).  This caused the 75 char limit to fail and the buffer to be printed.